# How to implement or bind jqgrid using ashx handler in asp.net C#

Tags: asp.net

I want to implement and bind jqgrid with ashx handler in MVP architecture, also that jqgrid shows only 10 records from the database whether it consists of 100 but only show 10 records, while in case if i search record that is not present in the listed 10 records then it should show from the database.Please help!

Comment: Can you show us your code, where it's doing that ?

Comment: I have not implemented yet the same. i want to do it from start. could you able to help me out with the implementation process ...if not in MVP then in simply asp.net C#

Answer (score 0):

Whats the problem in implementing ? 

A lot of sample available on the website .

You should try at least once before you ask question 
**HTML**

...

```
<table id="list2"></table>
<div id="pager2"></div>
Java Scrpt code
```

...

```
jQuery("#list2").jqGrid({
    url:'server.php?q=2',
    datatype: "json",
    colNames:['Inv No','Date', 'Client', 'Amount','Tax','Total','Notes'],
    colModel:[
        {name:'id',index:'id', width:55},
        {name:'invdate',index:'invdate', width:90},
        {name:'name',index:'name asc, invdate', width:100},
        {name:'amount',index:'amount', width:80, align:"right"},
        {name:'tax',index:'tax', width:80, align:"right"},      
        {name:'total',index:'total', width:80,align:"right"},       
        {name:'note',index:'note', width:150, sortable:false}       
    ],
    rowNum:10,
    rowList:[10,20,30],
    pager: '#pager2',
    sortname: 'id',
    viewrecords: true,
    sortorder: "desc",
    caption:"JSON Example"
});
jQuery("#list2").jqGrid('navGrid','#pager2',{edit:false,add:false,del:false});
```

Url wil be your source page , it can be a webservice , colmodel is a array holding data to display . Other options are pretty self explanatory

Comment: I want this code to be implemented with the help of generic handler!